# Elliptic curves and prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $p_n$ be the $n^{th}$ prime number. Suppose $E(F_{p_n})$ denotes an elliptic curve over the Galois field $GF(p_n)$ which is defined by $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. Is the below claim true?

For each integer number $n>3$, there exist integer numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\#E(F_{p_n})=p_{n+1}$?

Comment: Why do you believe such a thing is true?

Comment: This is stronger than the Riemann Hypothesis

Comment: I think that with finding such $a,b$, we can generating all prime numbers.

Comment: @Meysam: I am very confused by your last comment.  Note in particular that in your formulation you allow $a$ and $b$ to depend on $n$.  If you didn't mean that -- i.e., if you wanted to consider reductions of a fixed elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, the answer is certainly **no** (it follows from Serre's theorems on the image of the $\ell$-adic Galois representation.)

Comment: For each $n$ at first we find such $a,b$, and then we can generate next prime number.

Comment: Well, I suppose it depends what you mean by "generate".   Certainly I don't see anything algorithmically useful coming out of this.  But as I was happy to answer your question without hearing what was behind it, I will not further pester you about your motivations.

Comment: How we can find such $a,b$ without complete search? and whats the relation between $a,b$ and $p_n$ ?

Comment: @Meysam: Yes, exactly.  That's why I don't see anything algorithmically useful coming out of your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Sorry, I misread the question at first.)  The following result reduces your question to a problem of analytic number theory:

**Theorem** (Hasse-Deuring-Waterhouse): For a prime $p$ and $N \geq 1$ the following are equivalent:
(i) There is an elliptic curve $E_{/\mathbb{F}_p}$ such that $\# E(\mathbb{F}_p) = N$.
(ii) We have $|N-(p+1)| \leq 2\sqrt{p}$.

As long as $p > 3$ (i.e., $p = p_n$ for $n \geq 3$) every elliptic curve can be put in "short Weierstrass form" $y^2 = x^3 + ax +b$.

So you are reduced to asking: is it true that for all $n > 3$ we have 
$|p_{n+1} - (p_n+1)| \leq 2 \sqrt{p_n}$?

According to [this esteemed source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds), having this kind of upper bound on the prime gap (always) is conjectured to be true but far from being proven.  In fact, if I have it right this precisely [Andrica's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica's_conjecture).  As Dror Speiser points out, it is not even known conditionally on the Riemann Hypothesis.